How to determine if it's possible to light up all light bulbs?
Suppose you are given an NxN sudoku grid (with Rows 1,...N, and Columns 1,...N), with some arbitrary number of squares containing a light bulb.
Forget about the other squares.
Now, suppose that some of the light bulbs are turned on, others are turned off.
You only have one light switch per Row and Column. This switch changes the status for all the light bulbs in that row/column.
Is there an easy way to determine whether or not you can light up all bulbs at once from a certain starting configuration?
I managed to prove that this configuration [1 means on, 0 means off] (a specific configuration)
is impossible to solve. But I only managed to do it in a way that's based on arguments closely connected to the configuration itself. Is there a clever general way? Like an invariant that I just don't see, that works for all those problems?

If there are ever four lightbulbs in a square, i.e. at $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_1,y_2)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, $(x_2,y_1)$, and either $1$ or $3$ of them are on, then it is impossible as you cannot change the parity of this number.

See the lights out problem (change the logic a bit) https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LightsOutPuzzle.html

I think a recursive code can be implemented in polynomial time $O(N^3)$ Basically solve for $(N-1)*(N-1)$  and check if it is possible to do operation on the last row and column such that the condition is satisfied

@ArnabGoyal The $(N-1)\times (N-1)$ grid might have many solutions, only some of which can be extended to a solution of the $N\times N$ grid. It is certainly possible to do this method by computer, but I don't see it being simple enough in general for a human method. And if you're doing it by computer, then you might as well go straight to calculating the (partial) inversion of the full matrix.

@Henry's remark can be generalised. Such a square/rectangle can be seen as a loop of 4 lightbulbs where the bulbs are alternatingly connected horizontally/vertically. There may be longer loops like that in the grid, for example 6 bulbs arranged like the perimeter of an L-tetromino. All such loops must have an even number of lights off to be solvable, because every move affects exactly 2 (or none) of them so does not change the parity.

Assume every square contains a light-bulb. Then a solution is valid if the xor of any two rows is either fully turned on or fully turned off. This can be generalized for arbitrary configurations: Given two rows let $s$ be the set of columns on which both contain light-bulbs. Then, on said columns, the rows will have either fully identical or fully opposite configurations. Another way to state this is: given any $4$ bulbs arranged in a rectangle (2 row sides and 2 column sides), the number of active bulbs must be even. It isn't necessary to check all of them to establish validity.

Consider the state of the light bulbs as a $k$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_2$ (the field with two elements), where $k$ is the number of light bulbs. Each state is represented by a vector with $1$ for off and $0$ for on. Switching a row or column corresponds to adding a vector that has $1$s for the bulbs in that row or column. The vectors corresponding to the $2N$ rows and columns span a vector space (whose dimension is at most $2N-1$ but may be less if there are few bulbs). A given configuration can be transformed into the zero state where all lamps are on if and only if it lies in this vector space. Checking that is then just a matter of linear algebra.

There is a simple visual description of the solution set - A configuration can be solved iff there exists a subset of rows and columns such that the light is on iff   it is in both subsets or neither subset. If we reorder the grid so that these subsets come first, then we have 4 quadrants where all the lights are on or off accordingly.

@MikeEarnest I thought I did account for not all squares having a light. Can you provide an example where what I said isn't true? $\quad$ If you edit the answer, then you can change your vote.
